# cannot produce error in client side in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filesystems

Everyone , I'm currently learning about fileSystem in node js . code below

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    fs.readFile('demofile1.html', (err,data)=>{
        if (err){
            res.writeHead(404, {'content-type':'text/html'})
            return res.end('404 Not Found')
        }
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'})
        res.write(data)
        return res.end()
    })
}).listen(80)
```

when i hit 'localhost' in the browser, it work fine . But when i intentally makes a mistake (assume typing 'localhost//anything' in the browser) , Im not getting any error . why is that ???
I wnt to show '404 not found' in the client side if any error occurs . Can You help me ???

Comment: What did you expect? You're unconditionally sending `"./demofile1.html"` no matter the content of the request.

Comment: The `err` variable is any errors when reading the file, it has nothing to do with the request.

Comment: first i use "demofile1.html" , but that doesnt work too . Then i tried it as "./demofile1.html"

Answer (score 3):

because your 'fs.readfile' function always works.

it is not affected by url. becuase you don't write like below.

```
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    if(req.url == 'something'){
        fs.readFile('demofile1.html', (err,data)=>{
            if (err){
                res.writeHead(404, {'content-type':'text/html'})
                return res.end('404 Not Found')
            }
            res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'})
            res.write(data)
            return res.end()
        })
    } 
    else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'content-type':'text/html'})
        return res.end('404 Not Found')
    }

}).listen(80)
```

Comment: Thanks . I read about url parser , where i can produce error as you say . Thats why I'm getting more confused about that error that was  not producing . Now I'm clear that My code only work if I mention any url in my code .